# How do you do DNS over SSH reliably?

Tags: ssh, dns, openssh

How do you do DNS over SSH using Windows client and linux server reliably?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you trying to do this in code (StackOverflow is programmers' resource)? What platform, what language, what dev.tool are you using?

Comment: Probably not programming-related. Belongs on www.superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reliable way to do it using socat -> ssh -> socat